# How can i make android application load its assets from external storage folder rather than its local assets folder builtin in apk?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to load application assets from external storage ("DCIM") folder rather than its ("apk") builtin ("assets") folder. Please tell me how to do it?
I have given read write permissions too and I have tried giving path by

```
 String pathToAssetFolder = "file://"+Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/assets/";
```

Please let me know how can i load these assets contents from external directory?

Comment: It is a bad practice to use resources outside of assets. because there is no guarantee that even the file you need exist there, let aside what might be content of it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i need to do this as i have no other option beside this. Can u please tell me how to do this?